# How to change the hash (#) in the query string URL to another identifier with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble trying to find an item that has a hash (#), I want to change the hash in the url to another identifier. For example, I have a url like this => `http://localhost:8088/stores/1/brands?q=#`  When searching with a hash, the url will change to something like this => `http://localhost:8088/stores/1/brands?q=%23`

How to replace like that and push it to current url?

```js
let currentUrl = 'http://localhost:8088/stores/1/brands?q=#';
let url = new URL(currentUrl);

url.searchParams.set("q", "#"); // setting param
url.hash='';

let newUrl = url.href; 
console.log(newUrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `searchParams.set` handles URL encoding for you already. If you want to pass `#` as the value of the parameter, then you should _use_ `"#"` in that call.

Comment: @CBroe i want to change "#" to "%23" and change current url to ```q=%23```

Comment: If you want to remove the `#` that is still appended at the end of your new URL, then do `url.hash = '';`

Comment: @CBroe but the url like this ```http://localhost:8088/stores/1/brands?q=%2523```, what is 25?

Comment: That is the percent character in your parameter value, which `searchParams.set` has applied URL encoding to (resulting in `%25`.) Did you not read what I said in my first comment? You want to add the parameter `q` with the value `#`- so specify `#` as the value, and not `%23`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `encodeURIComponent`.

E.g.

```
encodeURIComponent("#") // gives %23
```

You can read the detail on MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: how to implement it with the code I have?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly - can you not do `window.location.href = newUrl` and load the page with the `newUrl` after replacing whatever you need?

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace

```
let currentUrl = "http://localhost:8088/stores/1/brands?q=#";
str = currentUrl.replace("#", "023");
console.log(str);
```

Update :

if you want to set the url you can use

```
location.href = str;
```

but in order to stop the infinite loop you need to add a extra para like

```
    let currentUrl = "http://localhost:8088/stores/1/brands?q=#";
    str = currentUrl.replace("#", "023");
    console.log(str);
var hash = url.searchParams.get("hashset");
    if(hash !== "1") {
console.log(str+"&hashset=1");
location.href = str+"&hashset=1";
} else {
console.log("hash already set")
}
```

Comment: and how to replace in url? or push itu to url?

Comment: updated the answer